# How do I perfect time two elements on hover in CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-animations, transition

### I want to make an html and css navigation bar with shade effect when mouse put on hover on the links (the <*a*> element). I put icons (the <*i*> element) next to the menus in the <*a*> tags.

*The problem is that when i hover on one of the menus and after i remove my mouse from there the backwards event (ease-out) between the icon and the actual text is not in perfect timing.*

More info:
-my html and css are on separatefiles
-to execute css animations and transitions I use the -webkit- library.

**I will appreciete everyone that is willing to give me some help. <3**
Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Начало</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.jpg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="IndexStyle.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d2896764d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<nav class="nav">
     <!--<img src="logo2-removebg-preview.png" style="width: 170px; margin-left: 12px; margin-top: 5px;">-->
        <a style="pointer-events: none;">
        <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ff4757;"></span>
        <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ffa502"></span>
        <span class="dot" style="background-color: #2ed573;"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="Index.html"><i class="fas fa-house-damage"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;НАЧАЛО</a>
        <a href="HtmlPage.html"><i class="fas fa-code"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;HTML&CSS</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ИНСТРУМЕНТИ</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗАДАЧИ</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗА НАС</a> 
    </nav>
</center>



</body>
</html>
```

IndexStyle.css:

```
body {
    background-image: url(1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

.pro_column1{
  width: 15%;
}

.pro_column2{
  width: 85%;
}

.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  /*opacity: 60%;*/
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 850px;
    /*background:#3c6382;
  /*box-shadow:0px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
    /*border: solid black 2px;*/

}


.nav a {
  /*float: right;*/
  color: #747d8c;
    /*display: block;*/
  text-align: center;
    padding: 35px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
    /*position: fixed; /* or absolute */
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-animation: 0.5s ease-in forwards;

}





i {
    /*float: right;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #747d8c;
  padding: 32px 5px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; 
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .nav a{
    display: block;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .dot{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

}
```

Comment: You can just remove `background-color: inherit;` from the `i` style.

Comment: Well that just saved me, didn't it! Hahaha! Thank you, sir <3.